# Como comparar que una cadena tiene solo los carácteres que le indico? En Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web que realiza las operaciones matemáticas necesarias para hacer un subneteo de clase C, por esto mismo para realizar esto ocupo que el usuario ingrese en un `<input type="text">` la dirección IP y en otro  la cantidad de subredes que desea crear. Una dirección IP váñida ocupa cumplir con los siguientes requisitos:

a. Debe de tener entre 7 y 15 caracteres.

b. 3 de esos caracteres deben de ser puntos (".").

c. Los demás deben de ser solo números (no puede haber letras).

Para controlar esto hice una función validadora que valida si el valor de la dirección IP es válido:

```
function ipvalidator(input) {
    if (onlyNumbers.test(input.value) === true && input.value.length < 16 && input.value.length > 6 && dotCounter(input.value,".") === 3) {
        ipaddress = input.value;
        return true;
    } else {
        displayer.innerHTML = `Please enter an valid IP Address. ${input.value} is not a valid IP Address.`;
        return false;
    }
}
```

El problema surge con `onlyNumbers.test(input.value)`, `onlyNumbers` está definida así:

```
var onlyNumbers = new RegExp('0123456789.');
```

la cual retorna `false` y por eso no se valida la dirección IP

**Salida en la consola del navegador Chrome:**

```
dotCounter(text1.value,".")
3
text1.value.length
11
onlyNumbers.test(text1.value)
false
```

Las demás si retornan `true`

Entonces, mi pregunta es: **¿Qué método debo de usar para verificar si la cadena que el usuario ingresa tenga solo números y puntos ("0123456789.")?**

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola. Una consulta. No preferís usar una expresión regular que te valide que sea una ip válida? Sería mejor eso creo, ¿o no? Incluso podrías restringir el ingreso de caracteres en el input que no sean numeros y puntos, y usar la misma expresión regular para validar y para restringir el ingreso de caracteres. Avisame si te sirve que te ayudo con la expresión regular.

Comment: Saludos. Una opción es expresiones regulares. Otra es usando Split (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp); para este caso ya sea IP o Mascara de red teniendo como separador el punto ".", siempre tendrías que obtener un array de 4 elementos, si son más o menos asumes incorrecto; ya solo tendrías que evaluar c/u este en el rango de valor permitido y no sea cadena vacía (evitar un "192.168..1"; serian 4 elemento pero uno vacío).

Comment: Gracias a los dos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expresión que estás utilizando para validar la IP es el problema.

Afortunadamente verificar que una IP sea válida es un requerimiento bastante común, la expresión podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
var onlyNumbers = new RegExp('^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$');
```

Fuente: [www.regexpal.com/22](https://www.regexpal.com/22)

Comment: Muchas gracias, que grande.